# Xcode Archive Product Error - Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am receiving this error when I try to Archive my app.

[image]

I don't really know what could be wrong with the script because I haven't touched it.  But when I look at the error log (image below) I think the path may be off slightly because there are 2 slashes in the path.

[image]

I have tried the typical solutions.

1. Clean Project
2. Clear DerivedData folder
3. Update / Reinstall cocoapods
4. Quit Xcode and try again
5. Buy new macbook, reformat, burn old device, etc :)

Any help or insight would be much appreciated!